# Filter json collection by id in Javascript

Tags: angularjs

So I'm trying to retrieve a collection from this list below by the `id` in Javascript. How can I do that? I've been searching lately to find a way but I couldn't.

```
   {'id':1,"firstTeam":"Barcelona","secondTeam":"Real       Madrid","Time":"14:00","commentator":"Unknown","championship":"UEFA","channel":"BEIN SPORT","iframe":'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pQRO_5dtqrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'}

   {'id':2,"firstTeam":"Barcelona","secondTeam":"Real Madrid","Time":"14:00","commentator":"Unknown","championship":"UEFA","channel":"BEIN SPORT","iframe":'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pQRO_5dtqrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'}
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. Is the above an array?

Comment: Yes it is an array : var IframesList=[ { the objects i've just pasted }, {second object}]. and every line has an id.

Comment: By "collection by id", you mean, you search for one or more id values and want the rows back? What have you been trying so far? Please post a little bit context: How would you like the extraction of the id's to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
 var testArray = [{'id':1,"firstTeam":"Barcelona","secondTeam":"Real Madrid","Time":"14:00","commentator":"Unknown","championship":"UEFA","channel":"BEIN SPORT","iframe":'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pQRO_5dtqrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'},
{'id':2,"firstTeam":"Barcelona","secondTeam":"Real Madrid","Time":"14:00","commentator":"Unknown","championship":"UEFA","channel":"BEIN SPORT","iframe":''}];

var filtered = testArray.filter(filterFunction);

// Let's assume you want to filter by ID, stored in $scope variable.
$scope.filterById = 2;


function filterFunction(val) {
  return value.id == $scope.filterById;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is dup of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Using [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
$.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.id == id; })[0]
```

Comment: Thank alot that's what i was looking for.